# Can we obfuscate java web application using proguard?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, proguard

Can we obfuscate java web application using proguard?
I have developed web application using spring boot, Now i have to deploy .WAR file of project at client end but for security reason i have to obfuscate the code.
Please guide me the proper way to obfuscate the code using Proguard.

Comment: What have you tried so far? ProGuard is free, so you can try it out without problems.

Comment: Till now what i did is..
1. created  .WAR file of source code.
2. changed above file extension to .jar and extracted the file by right clicking on it like we extract .rar file
3. Created jar of webapp classes (/WEB-INF/classes) called webapp.jar
4. Created jar of web.xml called web.xml.jar
5. In proguard input/output tab i have given he path of all jar files( point 3, 4) in Add input 
It gives me "Note: there were 140 duplicate class definitions.
"

Comment: You should integrate proguard as part of your maven/gradle (whatever you're using) build. Not _after_ building the war file.

Comment: Check out this sample project: https://github.com/seregaSLM/proguard-spring-boot-example

Comment: @Strelok yes i did that. 
the steps I have mentioned are correct? or I am missing something